# aireplay-ng command not found

Tags: linux, command-line, path, administrator, root

I just downloaded and installed Kali Linux on my MacBook Pro (dual boot) to mess around with penetration testing - I have experience with aircrack-ng, but it was a while ago (and I was at least unaware of the distributions geared towards penetration testing). Finally got everything up and running, and customized the way I want - I tried to run the basic injection test `aireplay-ng -9 wlan0` in the terminal and I get `command not found` when I try it as admin. The weird thing is it seems to work as root (I didn't try running the test - I just typed in `aireplay-ng` to see if it recognized the command, and it does). I don't think it is a PATH problem, but I added `/usr/sbin/aireplay-ng` to `/root/.bashrc` like this (just incase):

```
PATH=~/usr/sbin/aireplay-ng:$PATH
```

I don't think it is the path, because - as you can see, aireplay-ng is located in `/usr/sbin/` which is already part of my PATH variable (noticeable when I execute `echo $PATH`).

The odd part is - when I log in as root, it seems to work - I didn't actually run the test as root (probably not the best idea), but I did type in `aireplay-ng` to see if the command was recognized, and it was. Not sure if a symlink would help - but I'm not going to try anything until I get a response.

Just trying to get the aireplay-ng command recognized. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a issue with your `$PATH` if it works as `root` but does not as normal user (`aireplay-ng` is installed in an `sbin`-directory, which normally only appears in `$PATH` when logged in as `root`).  This is on purpose, though, since you need special privileges to run `aireplay-ng` (you want to fiddle with your network card, though, which shouldn't be possible for every normal user, should it?).

Comment: thanks! and yes i do like fiddling lol - so you are saying that i am supposed to run these tests as root? i thought that might be a bad idea (usually doing anything as root is frowned upon lol).

Comment: you are right about path! just did `echo $PATH` as normal user and sbin isnt there - how do i change this for this user?

Comment: You could modify your shell's startup files (`~/.bashrc` for `bash`, `~/.zshrc` for `zsh`), but I guess this won't help.  I think you'd have to run `aireplay-ng` as `root`.

Comment: ok - i guess there isnt a problem - thanks for your help!